# Java Regex - Exclude 5 digit numbers attached by a hypen

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex `(?:^|[^\w])(\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?)(?:$|[^\w])`.

It's looking for either a US standard 5 digit zip code or the longer 5+4 digit version.

However, this particular regex also matches on 5 digits for numbers of the following form.

`1111-11111`. The `11111` matches. How can I exclude this type of case?

I've tried adding the hypen to the exclusion at the beginning of the regex like so, `(?:^|[^\w]|-)` which had no effect.

Comment: Fixed it myself. (?:^|[^\w-])(\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?)(?:$|[^\w-]). Added the hypen to the wrong place.

Comment: Do you actually want to exclude `11111` and `11111-1111` values or only after hyphen? I guess you'd rather edit the question, like you want to avoid matching `12345` in `19875-12345`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can actually use

```
\b(?<!-)\d{5}(?:[- ]\d{4})?(?!-)\b
```

which is shorter and more readable. The `(?<!-)` negative lookbehind will make sure no `-` precedes the value, `(?!-)` negative lookahead will make sure no `-` follows the value, and `\b` word boundaries will effectively replace the `(?:^|\W)` and `(?:$|\W)` non-capturing groups.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL9qL8/2).